# Why do some angular material color inputs have a color input, and others do not?

Tags: angular-material

Components like `button`, `toolbar` allow for a color input like `<button color="primary">`, which is handy because it automatically updates the color of the text inside. But when I just wne to color a  component with color, I realized that it doesn't allow for a color input.

Browsing briefly through the marterial component docs, it seems to me entirely random whether a component accepts a color input or not. Is there any rhyme or reason to this? I'd be much happier if every component could have a color input.

Comment: I think its just based on the material design spec, where generally everything is grayscale except for a toolbar and the important buttons. https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-palettes

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had not internalized (but now understand) that, under material design, there are many parts of an interface that you are simply *discouraged* to color (roughly speaking the 'body' of your content), and that these not-to-be-colored parts are made greyscale (light or dark depending on your theme). To-be-colored items tend to be banners, navigators, buttons, etc.

I found it instructive to go through the [list of components](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) and put each one into one of two lists depending on whether they allow for a color directive:

### DO HAVE COLOR DIRECTIVE:

- mat-checkbox
- mat-datepicker
- mat-form-field
- mat-radio-group
- mat-radio-button
- mat-slider
- mat-slide-toggle
- mat-toolbar
- mat-list-option
- mat-selection-list
- mat-tab-nav-bar (`<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">`)
- mat-tab-group
- mat-button (`<button mat-button>Basic</button>`)
- matBadge (`<span matBadge="4" matBadgeColor="accent">Text with a badge</span>`)
- mat-chip
- mat-icon
- mat-spinner
- mat-progress-spinner
- mat-progress-bar
- matRipple (`<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="myColor"></div>`)
- mat-paginator

### DO **NOT** HAVE COLOR DIRECTIVE:

- mat-autocomplete
- matInput (`<input matInput>`)
- mat-select
- mat-menu
- mat-drawer-content
- mat-drawer
- mat-drawer-container
- mat-sidenav-content
- mat-sidenav
- mat-sidenav-container
- mat-toolbar-row
- mat-card
- mat-divider
- mat-accordion
- mat-expansion-panel
- mat-action-row
- mat-expansion-panel-header
- mat-grid-list
- mat-grid-tile
- mat-grid-tile-header
- mat-grid-tile-footer
- mat-nav-list
- mat-list
- mat-list-item
- mat-horizontal-stepper
- mat-step
- mat-tab
- mat-tree-node
- mat-tree
- mat-button-toggle-group
- mat-button-toggle
- mat-chip-list
- MatBottomSheet
- MatDialog
- MatSnackBar
- matTooltip
- MatSortHeader
- MatTable

**Note**: some of these are not compnents, per say, but are activated by e.g. a directive. In some (not all!) cases, I included in brackets how that 'component' is used.